# PHP DOM reads "Ã©" instead of "é"

Tags: php, dom, utf-8

I'm handling UTF8 data from an UTF8 database and I'm having trouble with UTF8 encoding.

1. Raw content is extracted correctly fron the DB and I do see "é" in my UTF8 terminal:

   ```
   Site de la Préfecture de Police
   ```
2. Then, when I pass this content through PHP functions operating with DOM, I see that:

   ```
   Site de la Pr&Atilde;&copy;fecture de Police
   ```
  We can see that DOM read `Ã©` instead of `é` and replaced `Ã©` with HTML entities `Ã©`.
3. After, I pass again through DOM functions and I get another strange conversion:

   ```
   Site de la PrÃ©fecture de Police
   ```

Now it looks like hexadecimal encoding of `é` : `%C3 %A9`

Do you know what's happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found it !

Two PHP functions where involved in the problem :

- `html_entity_decode` was working in ISO-8859-1
- `$dom->loadHTML($xml)` was working in ASCII

I fixed by setting the desired charset :

- `html_entity_decode( $newContent, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );`
- `$dom->loadHTML('<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>' . $xml . '</body></html>');`

Comment: Life savior Franck, that "loadHTML" modification did it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try charset: iso-8859-1 instead of UTF-8
or be sure to set the charset in your html header:

```
PHP : header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
HTML: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: I tried with latin1 charset and that did not change anything.

Comment: Have you set your charset in the html header ?
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: I forgot to mention that this script operates in CLI.